# Rotate direction of title of secondary axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I need to put an additional right-hand y axis on a graph. I have managed to do that in ggplot using the code below. But the text direction for that axis is opposite to that for the primary y axis. I have been asked to make the text directions the same. I have searched for instructions for that in the ggplot help and online but nowhere can I find anything about how to control the direction of a secondary axis title (tick labels yes, titles no).

I would be grateful if anybody can tell me how to do this. Thank you.

```
tbbl <- tibble(ltrs = letters,
               nums = rnorm(26)) %>%
  mutate(rownum = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(colr = factor(.$rownum %% 2, levels = 0:1) )

gx <- ggplot(data = tbbl, aes(x = rownum)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = nums, colour = colr, fill = colr)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 4.184, 
                                         name = 'Long title that my client finds hard to read if aligned the default way')) +
  labs(x = 'title for x axis', y = 'title for y axis')
print(gx)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the angle of the secondary y axis title via theme option `axis.title.y.right`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

tbbl <- tibble(ltrs = letters,
               nums = rnorm(26)) %>%
  mutate(rownum = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(colr = factor(.$rownum %% 2, levels = 0:1) )

ggplot(data = tbbl, aes(x = rownum)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = nums, colour = colr, fill = colr)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 4.184, 
                                         name = 'Long title that my client finds hard to read if aligned the default way')) +
  labs(x = 'title for x axis', y = 'title for y axis') +
  theme(axis.title.y.right = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I needed! Could I ask how you discovered that substituting "y.right" for "y" enables one to refer to the second axis? I could not find that information anywhere in the documentation. Unfortunately, I often find that documentation on ggplot and tidyverse functions is sparse, both in the help and on tidyverse.org. I have been engaged in migrating code to tidyverse but am starting to fear that may have been a mistake, given the sparseness and inconsistency of the help documentation - compared to the documentation for base R.

Comment: Hm. I had a hard start too. But after I managed to get into the philospohy behind ggplot2, .i.e the grammar of graphics I fell in love with ggplot2. (; I don't know base plotting that well but I guess what's probably confusing in the beginning is that e.g. axes are controlled by different layers, e.g. we have scales, coords and finally the theme which controls the non-data elements or the overall look of the plot. That's why I knew where I had to look the options up. See https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html#arguments. Best S.

Comment: Thank you again. That link seems to be the complete list of nouns that I could not find. I have bookmarked it for future reference.